# How to fix Android WebView crash due to pending MotionEvent

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-webview

My Android app is experiencing this crash randomly during operation, and I think it is due to a pending MotionEvent that is dispatched to a null object, but not sure.

here is the crash output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.getRequestInterceptor(BrowserFrame.java:1108)
at android.webkit.FrameLoader.handleRequestIntercept(FrameLoader.java:426)
at android.webkit.FrameLoader.handleHTTPLoad(FrameLoader.java:226)
at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:124)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

My Android app manually creates a custom WebView and adds it to the ViewGroup in the Activity.onCreate() method like this:

```
ViewGroup groupA = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_rowA);
webViewRowA = new MyWebView(this);
groupA.addView(webViewRowA);
```

The reason for doing it this way was to be able to get to the constructor for the WebView in order to pass *getApplicationContext()* instead of *this* to the constructor, which was a workaround for a memory leak in 2.1.

The issue, I think, is that this Activity is restarted frequently.  This causes the normal chain of onStop(), onDestroy(), onCreate(), etc... to happen often.

So my question is, could the crashes be due to a MotionEvent being dispatched to an instance of MyWebView that was attached to an old Activity that has been garbage collected?  Such as if the user clicked something in a webview right before this actvity was recycled?

Another thing to note is I'm seeing these messages following a call to onDestroy()

```
/webviewglue(  436): nativeDestroy view: 0xd738d0
```

Any help or insight anyone might have, would be greatly appreciated.  I've been banging away at this issue for a while now.

Oh, one other thing to note....this started happening in Android OS 2.2.  I've submitted a bug to Google, but not sure it is their issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The android market gives me 360 reports a week about this issue.

The problem is that my webview is not even created on the fly.

I have found this on the web: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11533

Still waiting for replies.

It looks like it's related to some phone models. Could you replicate this issue? I've never been able.

Thanks
rafa